# Magento changes in .phtml page is not reflecting

Tags: magento

I'm customizing the product page in the `view.phtml` file, The changes which I'm doing are not showing in the frontend. Even adding a `<p>` tag is not reflecting in the frontend. All the `css` changes are working properly.

Essentially, changes in phtml files only not working.

Comment: You haven't accepted answers for any of the 9 questions you've asked. You really should do this as it makes SO work much better, and people will be more willing to help. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing more frustrating to put lots of effort into an answer then only get points from random passers-by who do appreciate the work.

Comment: thanks guys... I solved the issue by using temmplate path hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

- In the admin go to `System->Configuration->Developer` and turn on `Template Path Hints` - this will tell you which template file controls which block. Check you are editing the correct file. (note, this is not suitable for a production server/live site).
- Have you cleared the cache?